# R ggplot Colors Don't match between different plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to ggplot, but cannot figure out why this is happening.  I have am trying to generate geom_bar plots with each column a different color within a facet, but the same for different facets.  It is doing that for me, but the problem is when I run these two similar codes my color scheme changes.  I've researched colorschemes and manually modifying it, but nothing is working.  Below are my codes and the different outputs I'm getting.

```
ggplot(dat.m,aes(x = `Prod Zone`,y = Average, fill = `Prod Zone`)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free") + 
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90,hjust = 1,vjust = .4),
      text = element_text(size = 15,face = "bold")) + 
      guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = VintageComp, y = value, fill = `VintageComp`)) + 
guides(fill = FALSE) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_y") + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust =.4),  
      text=element_text(size = 30, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

Everything is exactly how I want it to look, but the coloring.  For this example I want the first color scheme (rainbow looking) for both plots, I'd like to be able to choose a color scheme manually if someone could help me with that in this type of format.

Comment: The top plots have a discrete color scale whereas the bottom plots have a continuous color scale. These are dependent on whether the `fill` variable is continuous or discrete. Look at the [docs](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html) for gradient color scales.

Comment: Try replacing `VintageComp` with `factor(VintageComp)` in the second plot.  Although the colours might still differ as you have seven bars in one plot and six in the other.

Comment: Y'all are correct! It was the continues data of VintageComp.  I changed the data type dat.m$VintageComp<-factor(dat.m$VintageComp) and it worked perfectly. Thank y'all!

Comment: Just a note here that I think @Andrew Gustar was trying to get at is that you can use factor(variable) within the code of ggplot so you don't necessarily have to change the variable to a factor in the dataframe.